# Can I create a jQuery UI date picker under a certain div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a flyout menu `<div class="flyout">` which contains my date picker input. The flyout menu closes when the user clicks outside its div. When jQuery UI creates a date picker, it creates directly under `<body>` tag.  As a result when I try to click the prev/next button on my date picker, my flyout menu closes and leaves my date picker in the body. I do not want inline date picker but I want to create my date picker under my flyout div. Is there any way to achieve that?

my current html structure

```
<body>
<div class="main_pane"> </div>
    <div class="flyout">
      <label class="date">date:</label> <input class="start_date" id="from"/> 
    </div>
<body>
```

my date picker

```
$("#from").datepicker({
          dayNamesMin: [ "S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S" ], 
          firstDay: 1,  
          dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
          autoclose: true,
          onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );

          }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the `jQuery UI Datepicker` widget has an exposed event handler you could manipulate after it's been created, but as it does the task quite quickly, this should do the trick:

```
$(function () {
    var datePicker = $("#from").datepicker({
        dayNamesMin: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"],
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: "d MM, yy",
        autoclose: true,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    // Use .appendTo() to move the element to another element.
    datePicker.datepicker("widget").appendTo($(".flyout"));
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/6c3nwco5/)

[jQuery UI Datepicker Widget API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-widget)